# Rearrange Git branches in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, git

I use Xcode's built-in Git/Hub integration for day-to-day use. In one project I made a branch, and when you use Commit... Push to remote", you are asked to select which branch to push to.

The problem is that the branch, which is used only rarely, is the first entry in the push pop-up. I often check into the wrong branch during a push simply because I don't notice it is the default selection.

Is there any way to sort these entries, or temporarily mark one so it does not appear or is greyed out? You cannot drag them in the source control pane on the left and there do not appear to be any options anywhere.

Comment: "I often check into the wrong branch during a push". Does that mean you are pushing to the wrong remote branch? I assume this only happens the first time you push a new branch that isn't tracking a remote branch yet?

Comment: No, when I make a change and try to check it in using Xcode's Commit function, it checks it into the branch instead of main. This is simply because it is the first item in the list.

Comment: Oh, so maybe you didn't mean "push" there? I suppose you meant during "commit"?

Comment: Note that "commit" happens locally on whatever branch you have checked out (or on no branch if you don't have any branch checked out), and then "push" will push those commits to a remote server, syncing your local branch with the remote branch. If you have branch `main` currently checked out, it seems weird that a UI would allow you to accidentally commit your pending changes to a *different* branch, because you'd have to checkout that branch first before you commit to it.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry, I'm clicking the checkbox called "push to remote", which implies this is a push operation not a commit (well both). It's the list of push branches that is the problem. I have updated the question to clarify this.

Comment: Some Git users report that the Xcode Git interface is miserable. It sounds like you should learn and use the command line interface, and use Xcode as little as possible here.